# pandas comparing correlation tables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have several correlation tables in a list:

```
type(cormatrices[2])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

they for obvious reasons have values between -1 and 1. I want to compare them, and figure out if they revert back to the mean over time ( they are from different dates)

Is there an elegant way to do it. All I could come up with is

```
cormatrices[2]-cormatrices[1]
```

and then compare visually what happened

Answer (score 0):

You can try `corrcoef;`

```py
numpy corrcoef
```

Or You can try over `pyplot;`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


plt.matshow(dataframe.corr())
plt.show()
```